# Подвисание IIS сервера

Tags: asp.net, iis

Добрый день, коллеги.

Есть физический сервер на Win 2008 R2 + IIS 7.5, на нем крутятся несколько сайтов.
Раньше работал как часы, никаких проблем не наблюдалось, но последние дни, почти каждые сутки, в утренние часы (в районе 6-7 утра) IIS сервер подвисает и отказывается отвечать на запросы. Судя по сервисам мониторинга и по ответам через браузер от сервера просто нет никакого ответа - типичный Timeout (при этом на ВСЕХ сайтах). Так продолжается от двух до восьми минут, затем работа полностью восстанавливается. Во время таймаута IIS, на сервер можно без проблем зайти по RDP - в это время НЕ наблюдается какой-либо нестандартной нагрузки - процессоры загружены на 10-15%.

Перерыл все виндовые логи в EventViewer - там абсолютно никакой информации. Единственное, что в момент восстановления появляются записи для некоторых сайтов вида

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: HttpException 
Exception message: The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD.
at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
```

но это, судя по всему, связано с тем, что каким-то клиентам надоедает ждать и они рвут соединение.

В логах IIS по сайтам в период простоя обнаруживается дыра - нет ни одной записи, пока IIS висит. 
Так, например, за 06:24 более 200 записей, затем период простоя - ни одной записи и сразу записи уже за 06:31.

Как считаете, что это может быть, в какую сторону копать?
Спасибо.

Comment: Предположу, какой-то бот сканирующий засылает запросы от которых сервер давиться. На своём apache почти каждый день вижу всякие странные запросы, иногда система их детектирует как эксплоиты.

Comment: Но тогда бы, по идее, давился весь сервер и не позволял бы зайти по RDP, а нагрузка на ЦП была бы видимой. Но ничего этого нет - нагрузка процессоров низкая, по RDP подключение проходит.

Comment: Не обязательно, служба HTTP ведь живёт своей жизнью, а эксплоит может временно в отказ вводить службу, не обязательно загружая процессор. Надо изучать логи службы.

Comment: Стоит посмотреть список запросов в IIS Manager / Worker Processes / Current Requests - не висят ли там запросы в ожидании чего-то. Возможно, подключится отладчиком (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/919790), снять дамп и посмотреть чем там IIS занимается в это время.